# NSMutableArray Access Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management

I (think I) know what you're thinking... not another `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` question but I'm really struggling and it's driving me crazy. I've searched high and low all over the net *and* on here and the issue I'm facing seems have something to do with my memory management.

**Problem:**

Basically I have an `NSMutableArray` that keeps track of some cyber food. Since food can be added and taken away at the same time I have a separate array that checks for items to remove and holds the ones that **don't** need to be taken out. The idea is to then clear the original array (**_food**) and copy back all the items saved in the temporary array (**foodToKeep**). Here's the code

```
NSMutableArray *foodToKeep = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (Food *food in _food) {
    if(!food.removeable){
        [foodToKeep addObject:food];
        [food release];
    }
}

if(foodToKeep > 0){
  [_food removeAllObjects];

  for (Food *food in foodToKeep) {
      [_food addObject:food]; // EXC_BAD_ACCESS error here
      [food release];
      }
  }
}

[foodToKeep release];
```

I get the bad access error when add the food to the original array. After searching around it sounds like the **`_food`** array is being  released somewhere or somehow ending up as *nil*. The only place I have a `release` for _food is in the `dealloc` method so I can't understand why this is happening.

I'm fairly new to Objective-C (so go easy on me!) but as far as I can tell there are no leaks and no accidental releases that are causing this, I think what I need is an experts eye to see what is most likely a trivial mistake on my part :-P

**Edit:**
Food is defined and allocated here:

```
    @interface MainLayer
    {
        NSMutableArray *_food;
    }
```

In the class `init` method

```
    _food = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: where is _food defined..give the code

Comment: @Shubhank modified the question :)

Comment: Your second for...in clause is unnecessary; you can instead use `[_food addObjectsFromArray:foodToKeep];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are *overreleasing* here:

```
for (Food *food in _food) {
    if(!food.removeable){
        [foodToKeep addObject:food];
        // [food release];  <--- REMOVE THIS
    }
}
```

And here

```
for (Food *food in foodToKeep) {
      [_food addObject:food]; // EXC_BAD_ACCESS error here
      // [food release]; <--- REMOVE THIS
}
```

Remove the extra releases and you should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

You are releasing `Food` objects you don't own. Have a look at Objective-C [Memory Management Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).

In fact, in the line:

```
for (Food *food in _food) {
```

You don't own the object food, so you should not release it in the first loop, nor in the second loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are releasing `food` after you added it to the array, but the release doesn't balance a `retain` call so when you reach `[_food removeAllObjects]` presumably all Food objects get deallocated there and hence it crashes when you try to access it again later.